# PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, paypal, paypal-express

I have been recieving this email from paypal

> Hello XXXXXXXXXX,
>
> Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:
>
> https://XXXXXXXXXX/paypal/ipn/
>
> If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider
>   that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider
>   with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be
>   disabled for your account.
>
> Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.
>
> Thanks, PayPal
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------- PROTECT YOUR PASSWORD
>
> NEVER give your password to anyone, including PayPal employees.
>   Protect yourself against fraudulent websites by opening a new web
>   browser (e.g. Internet Explorer or Firefox) and typing in the PayPal
>   URL every time you log in to your account.
>
> ---
>
> Please do not reply to this email. We are unable to respond to
>   inquiries sent to this address. For immediate answers to your
>   questions, visit our Help Centre by clicking "Help" located on any
>   PayPal page or email.
>
> PayPal is committed to your privacy, learn more about our privacy
>   policy: https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full

I do not know why I am receiving this as all my Paypal Payments seem to be going through fine. I only use this paypal account for my magento store too (no ebay or other selling channels). And on magento I am only utilizing express checkout right now. How would I find the source of the problem and fix it?

Thanks

Comment: is order status was changing to processing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to disable this messages under PayPal account at:

Profile >> Selling Preferences >> Instant Payment Notification Preferences >> Edit IPN Settings >> Do Not Receive IPN Messages.

This way you can make sure if these e-mails are really coming from PayPal. If so, it means that PayPal is not getting success (200 OK status) reply in response to it's IPN notification and retrying it. This may happen due to some issues on your server, for example lost network connectivity for some small periods, that are not noticeable with normal browsing.